# Handling processing overhead due to request time out

Tags: algorithm

Consider a service running on a server for a customer c1,but customer c1 times out after 'S' sec for what so ever be the reason so customer again fires the same request ,so server is running duplicate query hence it gets overloaded, resolve this glitch. Please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on the server side and hence cannot control multiple requests coming in from the same client.

Every client should be having an IP address associated with them. In your load balancer(if you have one) or in your server you need to keep an in-memory cache which keeps track of all requests, their IP addresses, timestamp when request originated and timestamp when request processing finished. Next you define and appropriate time measure - which should be near about 70-80% percentile of processing time for all your requests. Lets say X seconds.

Now, before you accept any request at your loadbalancer/ server you need to check in this in-memory cache whether the same IP has sent the same request and the time elapsed since the last request is less than X. If so do not accept this request and instead send a custom error stating something like "previous request still under processing. Please try after some time".

In case IP address is not enough for identifying a client, as the same client may be sending requests to different endpoints on your server for different services, then you need to store another identifier which maybe a kind of token/session identifier - such as c1 or customer id in your case. Ideally, a customer can send only 1 request from 1 IP Address to an endpoint at any 1 point of time. Just in case you have mobile and web interfaces then you can add the channel-type(web/mobile/tablet) as well to the list of identifying parameters .

So now, a combination of - customer id(c1), IP address, request URL,request time, channel-type will always be unique for a request coming in. Using a key of all these parameters in your cache to uniquely fetch information for a request and validating whether to start processing the request or send a custom error message to prevent overloading the server with re-requests - should solve the problem defined above.

Note - 'S' seconds i.e. client-side timeout - given that the client-side timeout is not in our control -  should not concern the server-side and will have no bearing on the design I have detailed above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dhruv. It was really informative and fruitful.